# q - recursion with /

Tags: kdb, q-lang

In q, a common illustration for the `over` operator `/` is the [implementation of fibonacci sequence](http://code.kx.com/q4m3/1_Q_Shock_and_Awe/#112-example-fibonacci-numbers)

```
10 {x,sum -2#x}/ 1 1
```

This indeed prints the first 10 fibonacci numbers but doesn't make sense in regards of the definition of the `over` operator in this [whitepaper](https://code.kx.com/q/wp/efficient_use_of_adverbs.pdf) (page 8)

> With two arguments, the second one being a list, the function is
>   called with the left argument as its first parameter and the first
>   element of the right argument as the second parameter. Next, the
>   function is called with the result of the previous iteration as the
>   first parameter and the third element as the second parameter. The
>   process continues in this way for the remaining elements of the list.

So in the fibonacci example above, at the first iteration the function would be called with `[10;1]` ("first parameter and first item of second parameter") which would already give an incorrect result.

My implementation is in line with the definition (and works)

```
1 1 {[l;c] l,sum -2#l}/til 10
```

but I don't like it because the parameter `c` is never used.

How can the first example be reconciled with the definition?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/ has a number of forms, described here: https://code.kx.com/q/ref/adverbs

The specific form being used here is "repeat" - https://code.kx.com/q/ref/adverbs/#converge-repeat

The fibonacci function here is monadic i.e. takes one parameter (x)

In this form, / will run the function with the supplied parameter (i.e. the list of 1 1), and then with the result of that call, and then again with the result of that call and so, until the number of iterations reaches 10 (the left argument to /)

The definition you provide is true if the function is a dyadic function (i.e. takes two parameters)

Hope this helps

Jonathon

AquaQ Analytics

Answer (score 1):

The left argument is this example is being treated as an iteration integer atom (repeat).

Please see [coverge-repeat](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/adverbs/#converge-repeat) on code.kx.com may add further clarification.